# Excel: Compare two columns and find differences between numbers (from round brackets )

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to compare two columns and find differences between numbers (from round brackets). I have pointed out the differences but I do not know how to compare the two tables to find them.

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output? Please post a screenshot only from the relevant part of your screen, so we can read it without zooming.

Comment: check this:  https://snag.gy/oGgOHT.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you are probably looking for is:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("(",A1)+1)=RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-SEARCH("(",B1)+1),"Same Nr","Different Number")
```

Explanation:
The Length of the *(123)* part

```
             LEN(A1)-SEARCH("(",A1)+1
```

Cutting the *(123)* out of the text

```
    RIGHT(A2,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("(",A1)+1)
```

The same for column B

```
                                       RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-SEARCH("(",B1)+1)
```

comparing it

```
    RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("(",A1)+1)=RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-SEARCH("(",B1)+1)
```

And then putting it it in an IF statement (or do whatever you want)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming strings in A and B, you could calculate the difference between the number inside the brackets.

`=MID(A1, FIND("(", A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1) - MID(B1, FIND("(", B1)+1,LEN(B1)-FIND("(",B1)-1)`

Extract the string (here numbers) between the brackets for A1 and B1 and substracting.
It's basically twice the same formula using MID

`MID(A1, FIND("(", A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)`

- find the postion of the first ( bracket and start just after using FIND
- find the number of characters to read from the first ( bracket by substracting the total length and the position of the ( bracket and remove 1 which is the ) bracket
- extract using MID according to those the position and the number of characters
- Substract the two

but you might as well use RIGHT from Jounathaen.... faster...

Comment: Is there a typo? You say the function finds the first ")". But I can't find that in your code.

Comment: yes sorry, I updated the second bullet point, it's the number of characters to read..

Answer (score 0):

Create a third column, If you want to find case-sensitive matches between 2 columns in each row, then use the EXACT function:

=IF(EXACT(A2, B2), "Match", "")

Comment: doesn't work at me, can you add a print screen or an excel file to check again?